# Adobe Flash -selecting a specific section of the stage and playing a sound when an object reaches it

Tags: flash, select, actionscript, if-statement, adobe

here is the issue. I'm kind of new to flash, but have some knowledge so i am trying to create a little soccer game. i have the ball, the controls, the stage (soccer field) the issue is that i want to designate a part of the stage so if my ball goes into it plays a sound file that screams "Goal!!!" every time the ball goes into the arches...the stage is 800 x 600.

Any ideas on how i would implement this? any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

this is my code:

import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.*;

var begin = new Begin();
var pelota = new Pelota();
var field = new SoccerField();


//Calling methods game
beginGame();


//creating the welcome screen
function beginGame(){
    begin.x = 0;
    begin.y = 0;
    addChild(begin);

    pelota.x = 400;
    pelota.y = 425;
    addChild(pelota);

}

pelota.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);


function startGame(event:Event) : void{
    field.x = 400;
    field.y = 300;
    addChild(field);

    pelota.x = 400;
    pelota.y = 300;
    pelota.scaleX = .2;
    pelota.scaleY = .2;
    addChild(pelota);
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, control);

function control (evt:KeyboardEvent) : void 
{
    trace(evt.keyCode);

    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) 
    {
        pelota.x=pelota.x-5;
        trace('Left!');
    }
    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) 
    {
        pelota.x=pelota.x+5;
    } 
    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) 
    {
        pelota.y=pelota.y-5;
    } 
    if (evt.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) 
    {
        pelota.y=pelota.y+5;

    }
}

<pre><code>

Answer (score 0):

Two ways off the top of my head you could do this (I guessing the goal area is roughly a rectangle shape):

1.) Create the ball and goal as a movie clip/display object then simply do a hitTestObject () method call to check if they 'touch' each other. The actual 'trigger' area of the goal can be smaller then the visual area so that the ball only can touch it if it is visually all the way inside the goal.

2.) This is a circle vs. rectangle collision detection. You could solve the problem through pure math calculations. You should be able to find the actual algorithm by searching and isn't too difficult to write, especially if the goal-rectangle is axis aligned (at 0 or 90 degrees to the stage).

The second method will work faster and probably be more accurate, though the first can be a quick and dirty way of just getting it to work first. Both methods can just return a boolean that when true, you would play the sound. For playing the sound, look up the Sound{} class.

Comment: Hi, THANK YOU!!!! hitTestObject() worked like a charm...was pulling my hairs all day. Thank you once again.